# Python DBus Array of Structs

Tags: python-3.x, dbus

I have a C++ audio application which exposes a DBus interface with the following introspection info:

```
<node>
  <interface name="org.misc.player">
    <method name="setPlaylist">
      <arg name="list" type="a(ssb)" direction="in" />
      <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In0" value="Playlist"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

I tried to use the interface in python like this:

```
from pydbus import SystemBus
import dbus

player = SystemBus().get("org.misc.player", "/")
first_item = dbus.Struct((dbus.String("item1"),dbus.String("http://some_url.com/my.mp3"),dbus.Boolean(True)), signature='ssb')
playlist = dbus.Array([first_item])
player.setPlaylist(playlist)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
gi.repository.GLib.Error: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'setPlaylist' in interface 'org.misc.player' at object path '/' (signature 'a(ssb)') (19)
```

However when I try to use the interface from a Qt application with a generated proxy (qdbusxml2cpp) it works. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the application definitely exposed on the *system* bus? Typically, applications should be exposed on the *session* bus. System services (which are independent of the logged in user) are exposed on the system bus.

Comment: Yes the application is accesible on the SystemBus, other methods with "simpler" signatures work.

Comment: Try looking at the traffic using Bustle (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bustle/bustle) and see if that gives you any insight into what’s going wrong. It might show an error in the addressing of the call you’re making.

From the error message, it looks like the method name, object path or interface name are wrong, rather than the method arguments being wrong.